# Sort listitem in android based on timestamp when using Preference to store data

Tags: android, listview, sorting, timestamp, listitem

I am adding new item (OR sorting) in listview at the top using below code

```
items.add(0, new EntryItem(first, second));
```

and it works too, but sometimes when two things are triggered at same time, it won't sort particularly. Is there any way to sort listitem based on timestamp. I am using preferences hence for me to fetch timestamp is little difficult and do comparison based on it. Any other suitable way to sort listitems in listview based on timestamp ?

Comment: If you have the timestamp stored in milliseconds (a long), you can easily do comparisons.

Comment: Can you show me an example ?

Comment: Can you post the EntryItem class? Also, post relevant code which can be helpful to give you useful suggestions.